# Factory Muffin relationships are "null" when using instance method

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, factory-bot

I'm working on a Laravel 5 app using the [jenssegers\laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) package and I'm trying to get up and running with [Factory Muffin](https://factory-muffin.thephpleague.com/) to help with rapidly testing and seeding etc.

I have defined relationships in my factory definitions (code below) - and they work when I run seeds to create new records in the database. By "work", I mean they attach related data correctly to the parent model and persist all those records to the database. But they do not work when I run the `$muffin->instance('My\Object')` method, which creates a new instance without persisting it. All the relations come back as null.

In a way this makes sense. When the models are stored in the database, they are related by the object `_id` key. That key doesn't exist until the model is stored. So when I call the `instance` method, I actually can see via debugging that it does generate the models that *would* be related, but it does not yet have any key to establish the relation, so that data just kinda goes poof.

This is a bummer because I'd like to be able to generate a fully fleshed-out model with its relations and see for example whether it is saved or passes validation and whatnot when I submit its data to my routes and things. I.e., right now I would not be able to check that the contact's email was valid, etc.

Simplified code samples are below - am I going about this in an entirely wrong way? This is my first time working with Mongo and Factory Muffin. Should this even be able to work the way I want it to?

```
// factories/all.php
$fm->define('My\Models\Event', [
    'title' => Faker::text(75),
    'contact' => 'factory|My\Models\Contact'
]);

$fm->define('My\Models\Contact', [
    'first_name' => Faker::firstName(),
    'email' => Faker::email(),
    ... etc
]);

// EventControllerTest.php
...

/**
 * @var League\FactoryMuffin\FactoryMuffin
 */     
protected $muffin;

public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    $this->muffin = new FactoryMuffin();
    $this->muffin->loadFactories(base_path('tests/factories'));
}

...

public function testCanStoreEvent()
{
    $event = $this->muffin->instance('Quirks\Models\Event');
    echo $event->contact; // returns null
    $event_data = $event->toArray();

    $this->call('POST', 'events', $event_data);
    $retrieved_event = Event::where('title', '=', $event->title)->get()->first();

    $this->assertNotNull($retrieved_event); // passes
    $this->assertRedirectedToRoute('events.edit', $retrieved_event->id); // passes


    // So, the event is persisted and the controller redirects etc
    // BUT, related data is not persisted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in order to get factory muffin to properly flesh out mongo embedded relationships, you have to do like this:

```
// factories/all.php

$embedded_contact = function() {
    $definitions = [
        'first_name' => Faker::firstName(),
        'email' => Faker::email(),
        // ... etc
    ];

    return array_map(
        function($item) { return $item(); },
        $definitions
    );
}

$fm->define('My\Models\Event', [
    'title' => Faker::text(75),
    'contact' => $embedded_contact
]);
```

If that seems onerous and hacky ... I agree! I'm definitely interested to hear of easier methods for this. For now I'm proceeding as above and it's working for both testing and seeding.